# How can I clear / reset my contact form after successfully mail sent?

Tags: php, ajax, forms, reset

I got this mail.php. My contact form remains same with user submitted data even after email is sent successfully, aajaxalert says thank you its sent but that message stays only for few seconds if a dumb user misses this, then he might try clicking "send" message again. How can I reset whole form?

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    function sendFeedback($feedback_email, $feedback_msg,
            $feedback_name  , $feedback_subject)
     {
        /* EDIT THIS */
        $admin_email = "mail@website.com";
        if ($feedback_subject == "Subject" || empty($feedback_subject) ) {
            $subj = "Email from website.com.au";
        } else {
            $subj = $feedback_subject;
        }
        /* //EDIT THIS */

        $message = "
        <html>
        <head>
          <title>Email from your site</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p><a href='mailto:".$feedback_email."'>".$feedback_name."</a>
                       send this message:</p>
            <p>".$feedback_msg."</p>
            <p>".$subject."</p>
        </body>
        </html>
        ";
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

        if (($feedback_name!=="Name" &&
             $feedback_email!=="Email" &&
             !empty($feedback_email
           ) && (
                  !empty($feedback_msg) && 
                  !empty($feedback_name))
              {
            if($feedback_email == "mail_error")
            {
              echo "<span class='ajaxok'>$feedback_name , You entered an
                            Invalid email address.</span>";
            } else {            
                mail($admin_email, $subj, $message, $headers);
                echo "<span class='ajaxok'>Thank You! $feedback_name,
                                  Your message has been sent.</span>";  
                }
        } else {
            echo "<span class='ajaxalert'>Hi $feedback_name you forgot to type
                    the  message. </span>";     
        }   
    }

    sendFeedback($_POST['email'], 
      $_POST['message'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['subject']);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting response from ajax page you are showing message at that time you can reset or empty input fields using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the js `.reset()` function for this. It resets the form values to their defaults.

```
var form = getElementById('form_id');
form.reset();
```